# SQL PLUS Return ONLY the most frequent value in a column

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

SQL PLUS:
I am trying to return ONLY the most frequent 'MAKE' from one table and the 'NAME' of those customers from another table. This is what I have:

```
 SELECT sv.make, c.first, c.MI, c.last
  FROM Sales s
   INNER JOIN Sale_Vehicles sv
    ON s.VIN = sv.VIN
   INNER JOIN Customers c
    ON s.cust_ID = c.cust_ID
  GROUP BY sv.make, c.first, c.MI, c.last
  ORDER BY sv.make, COUNT (*) DESC;
```

This returns the most frequent 'MAKE' at the top of the results with the 2nd and 3rd below it. How do I only return the most frequent?

Comment: Look up how to add row numbers and put condition for rownum = 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH most_frequent AS (
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT sv.make
     FROM Sales s
     INNER JOIN Sale_Vehicles sv
       ON s.VIN = sv.VIN
     GROUP BY sv.make
     ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC
    )
WHERE rownum = 1 
)
SELECT sv.make, c.first, c.MI, c.last
  FROM Sales s
   INNER JOIN Sale_Vehicles sv
    ON s.VIN = sv.VIN
   INNER JOIN Customers c
    ON s.cust_ID = c.cust_ID
   INNER JOIN most_frequent mf
    ON sv.make=mf.make;
```

Answer (score 0):

could using the result as a subselect check for rownum

```
select * from ( 
 SELECT sv.make, c.first, c.MI, c.last
  FROM Sales s
   INNER JOIN Sale_Vehicles sv
    ON s.VIN = sv.VIN
   INNER JOIN Customers c
    ON s.cust_ID = c.cust_ID
  GROUP BY sv.make, c.first, c.MI, c.last
  ORDER BY sv.make, COUNT (*) DESC) T 
  where rownum =1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the most frequent MAKE (i.e. the one whose COUNT is the larges of all), you should ORDER BY COUNT first, not by MAKE. Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT sv.make, c.first, c.MI, c.last
     FROM Sales s
     INNER JOIN Sale_Vehicles sv
       ON s.VIN = sv.VIN
     INNER JOIN Customers c
       ON s.cust_ID = c.cust_ID
     GROUP BY sv.make, c.first, c.MI, c.last
     ORDER BY COUNT (*) DESC               --> different from your ORDER BY
    )
WHERE rownum = 1;
```

**[EDIT]**

Right; in case when more than one MAKE satisfies the condition, then RANK analytical function might help. Here's an example based on Scott's schema:

Job frequency:

```
SQL> select job, count(*)
  2  from emp
  3  group by job
  4  order by count(*) desc;

JOB         COUNT(*)
--------- ----------
CLERK              4
SALESMAN           4
MANAGER            3
ANALYST            2
PRESIDENT          1
```

Let's rank them:

```
SQL> select job, count(*),
  2    rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rn
  3  from emp
  4  group by job
  5  order by count(*) desc;

JOB         COUNT(*)         RN
--------- ---------- ----------
CLERK              4          1    --> these 2 should be returned as the 
SALESMAN           4          1    --> final result
MANAGER            3          3
ANALYST            2          4
PRESIDENT          1          5
```

The final result:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from (select job, count(*), rank() over (order by count(*) desc) rn
  3        from emp
  4        group by job)
  5  where rn = 1;

JOB         COUNT(*)         RN
--------- ---------- ----------
CLERK              4          1
SALESMAN           4          1
```

Applied to your query:

```
select *
  from (  select sv.make,
                 c.first,
                 c.mi,
                 c.last,
                 rank () over (order by count (*) desc) rn             --> new
            from sales s
                 inner join sale_vehicles sv on s.vin = sv.vin
                 inner join customers c on s.cust_id = c.cust_id
        group by sv.make,
                 c.first,
                 c.mi,
                 c.last)
 where rn = 1;
```

Any improvement?

Comment: This worked but it is only showing one customer name, not all the customers that are related to that MAKE. How do I make all the customers show as well?

Comment: @pCaMp, I've edited my message; please, have a look whether it makes any sense.